# How to get all tags associated with a content?

Tags: tags, liferay

I have some content in Liferay that is populated by front-end users, who can add some tags.

How can I get that tags associated with that content from back-end to do some stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use below method to get asset tags associated with content.
className would be of JournalArticle and classPK will be primarykey of content(journal article).
`AssetTagLocalServiceUtil.getTags(
        java.lang.String className, long classPK)`